# How to setup Facebook Comments plugin in my own webpage?

Tags: facebook, comments

I have read this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/ but I'm still not really sure about it.

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div><script
 src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1">></script><fb:comments
 href="**May I know What website should I put in here?**" num_posts="5"
 width="500"><meta property="fb:app_id" content="**MY APP ID? Whre can
 I find them?**"/></fb:comments>
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on the **Apps** link on the top bar. That should take you to your dashboard.
There you will find these keys, given that you created a new application.